# Link multiply small xcode projects

Tags: xcode

So I am working on a very large xcode project, with a lot of libraries, and sub directories which generates a huge pbxproj file, is there a way to generate smaller xcode projects or pbxproj files that can then be read into a main project.  Similar to how visual studio has a main vcproj file and smaller vcproj files for each library/executable etc...

Thanks for any input.

Answer (score 1):

You should break your project up into logical chunks. In ObjC world these chunks are called [frameworks](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/macosx/Conceptual/BPFrameworks/Concepts/WhatAreFrameworks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002303-BBCEIJFI). Then you can create a main project that incorporates your frameworks. It's cleaner and easier to maintain. Apple has a [framework programming guide](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/macosx/Conceptual/BPFrameworks/Frameworks.html).